# How to check how many days passed from timestamp - counting the days at midnight

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I'm trying to know how many days have passed from a certain timestamp, but the problem is I can't set it up, so that after midnight will count it as another day.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
<?php
$now = time(); // or your date as well
$your_date = 1572123244;
$datediff = $now - $your_date;

echo round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

If I put a timestamp of five minutes before midnight (1572134100), five minutes after midnight should appear that "one day passed"

Comment: Why should it say 2 days passed if only 10 minutes passed in reality?

Comment: I want to check how many days have passed.  Or check how many times it was midnight.

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake..it should say 1 day has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way of counting the days passed since a given timestamp would be something like this:

```
$dt = date_create_from_format('U', 1572046200);
$diff = $dt->diff(new DateTime());

echo $diff->days;
```

But this counts the full 24 hour periods as days. In your case you want to count calendar dates irrespective of the time of day. I would recommend then to ceil the timestamp to the midnight.

```
$dt = date_create_from_format('U', 1572047700);
$dt->setTime(0, 0); // set time to 00:00

$now = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // time now, but in UTC 
$now->setTime(0, 0); // set time to 00:00
$diff = $dt->diff($now);

echo $diff->days;
```

I am not sure about your current time zone, but timestamps are by nature in UTC, hence you should probably normalize your local time to UTC as well.

What this code does is it sets both today's date and the timestamp you are comparing against to the midnight of the UTC day and then calculates the difference between the two. Taking the time out of equation, this will always count the full 24 hour days.